# node webkit app-view permissions

Tags: node-webkit

I have a backbone web app and everything works fine in my browser. Now I want to make a .exe with Node webkit.

This is my package.json file:

```
{
"name": "XXXX",
"main": "index.html",
"window": {
    "toolbar": true,
    "width": 800,
    "height": 600
},
"single-instance": false,
"version": "1alpha",
"private": true
```

}

but when I execute the program I obtain these message in the js console:

```
You do not have permission to use the appview element. Be sure to declare the 'appview' permission in your manifest file and use the --enable-app-view command line flag.
```

I've been how to fix it [here](https://github.com/nwjs/nw.js/wiki/Manifest-format#chromium-args) but I didn't find any solution.

Any idea? thanks

Comment: Did you try "js-flags": "--enable-app-view"

Comment: Thanks. Yes, but the same error is shown.

Answer (score 0):

I have find any partial solution. If a change the main option to:

```
"main": "http://localhost:8000",
```

it works perfectly, but I need to start a little web server before and I don't want to do that. Any idea?